# Building Json Object from Vue input fields

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, methods, javascript-objects

Im trying to generate a JSON object with a vue method and using vue input data fields to build part of the JSON object. My input files accept a key and a value and i have two default values 'zone' and 'capping'. My goal is for the JSON object to be like:

```
{
"zone":{
  "capping":{
    "duration": 300
  }
 }
}
```

But instead i get a JSON object like this:

```
{
   "zone":{
      "capping":{
         "values":[
            {
               "key":"duration",
               "value":"300"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This is my vue method:

```
generateJson() {
      const values = this.inputs
      const loopedObj = values.forEach((item) => {
        const val = {
          ...item
        }
        return val
      })
      console.log(values)
      const jsonValues = {
        zone: {
          capping: {
            values
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonValues))
    }
```

This is the Vue code for the input fields:

```
<div>
          <p>3- Add Data</p>
          <button @click="showInput">+</button>
          <div v-for="(input, k) in inputs" :key="k">
            <input v-model="input.key" type="text" @change="getKey($event)" />
            <input
              v-model="input.value"
              type="text"
              @change="getValue($event)"
            />
          </div>
```

Any advice? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your template:

```html
<input v-model="input.key" type="text" @change="getKey($event)" />
<input
  v-model="input.value"
  type="text"
  @change="getValue($event)"
/>
```

it looks like your `input` is an object that has properties `key` and `value`:

```
inputs: [
  {
    key: "",
    value: ""
  }
]
```

When you did this:

```js
      const values = this.inputs
      const loopedObj = values.forEach((item) => {
        const val = {
          ...item
        }
        return val
      })
```

Problems are:

- you used `forEach` which just loops over the array. it won't return anything. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax). Maybe you meant `.map()`
- Even if you use `.map()`, what you did is just copy the object and so `loopedObj` will stil look like `this.inputs`. Almost the same as `values.map((item) => item))`

And now when you did this:

```
      const jsonValues = {
        zone: {
          capping: {
            values
          }
        }
      }
```

It's as if you just did:

```
      const jsonValues = {
        zone: {
          capping: {
            values: this.inputs
          }
        }
      }
```

Because `const values = this.inputs` never changed anywhere in your code. Never even tried to use `loopedObj` as well.

---

Solution:

```js
const values = {}

this.inputs.forEach((item) => {
  values[item.key] = item.value
})

const json = {
  zone: {
    capping: values
  }
}
```

Then maybe `JSON.stringify()` it if you need it.

Comment: Your solutions works, however after continuing my integration, the json object generated will generate numbers as strings with double quotes. (ex:  "duration":"300") this breaks my API put call since the value needs to be passed as a Number instead (without the double quotes). Do you know a way around this?